# How to change label text color of FormTextField when error

Tags: flutter, dart, validation

How to automatically change label text color of `TextFormField` in flutter?

Comment: Flutter does that automatically, when you provide a validation logic to the formfield´s validator.

Comment: Please make the question and you requirement bit more clear

Comment: Do you mean the field label you set with `inputDecoration`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class MyViewState extends State<MyView> {
  bool _invalidValue = false;

...

TextFormField(
  autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    icon: const Icon(Icons.person),
    hintText: 'What is your name?',
    labelText: 'Name',
    labelStyle:
    TextStyle(color: _invalidValue ? Colors.red : Colors.blue),
  ),
  validator: (String? value) {
    final b = (value != null && value.contains('@'));
    SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((timestamp) {
      if (_invalidValue != b) {
        setState(() {
          _invalidValue = b;
        });
      }
    });

    return b ? 'Do not use the @ char.' : null;
  },
)
```

The `b` variable is for preventing `setState` to be called every time, only when needed

Comment: why not just use setState without addPostFrameCallback? for it works